# long long функция выводит не те числа

Tags: c++, int

Тренируюсь работать с классами и возникла такая проблема,мне в задании сказали использовать функцию long long CalculateVolume() Для подсчета объема коробки.

Размер следующий:
1039 X 3749  X 847

Но вместо правильного ответа выдается вообще отрицательное число (-1355615565)

Пробовал использовать другие типы данных для функций по типу long long unsinged int но число которое выводится намного больше чем которое должно получится (18446744072353936051), тоесть когда выводится отрицательное я еще могу понять (памяти не хватает) но когда выводится число намного больше чем которое нужно и неправильно то тут уже не понятно. Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема? И какой вообще тип функции тут использовать?

Функция:

```
long long CalculateVolume() {
        return b*h*l;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, функцию. Мы тоже хотим такую.

Comment: В выражении `long long v = 1039 * 3749 * 847;` все промежуточные результаты (и даже окончательный результат) имеют тип `int`. Вы получаете переполнение. Делайте так: `long long v = 1039LL * 3749LL * 847LL;`

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey не понял вопроса?) что надо подсказать?) функция просто перемножает размер коробки, и при тех числах которые я указал она ломается

Comment: Это не полный код. Какого типа переменные `b`, `h`, `l`?

Comment: Все три типа int

Comment: `return (long long)b*h*l;` - так сработает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, так работает спасибо! Но я единственное не понимаю, функция же объявлена как long long, значит она и возвращать должна это значения, зачем нам переменные сами приводить к этому типу?

Comment: Вы же написали, что переменные типа int. Переполнение при вычислении возвращаемого значения

Comment: Когда компилятор компилирует выражение `b*h*l` он учитывает только типы переменных из выражения. Как там функция объявлена его не интересует. Смиритесь, так устроен язык C++ - тип арифметической операции определяется только типами её аргументов.